# Xamarin Use DataTemplateSelector not in ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I have a simple question.  I have two datatemplates defined on my Xamarin Forms page.  I want to swap one in for the other when a button is pressed.  I know with a `ListView` I can use the `ItemTemplate` and bind to my `DataTemplateSelector` to change views for the items in the list.

But I just want to swap something like a View/StackLayout/Frame by running the `DataTemplateSelector` on a button click or similar.  But I can't find any controls that offer an `ItemTemplate` list `ListView`.

Is there a control that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom control that would switch between 2 different views should not be that hard. You can expose a bindable property as a trigger for switching between views and handle the "switch" logic in the custom control it self.

I didn't try myself but it should be possible to work with `DataTemplateSelector`s in custom controls as well. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector#creating-a-datatemplateselector-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825489/datatemplateselector-createcontent-throws-invalidoperationexception).