# DataTemplateSelector CreateContent throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am in the process of making a custom horizontally scrollable ListView type control, I have come across an issue which I can't explain, and I'm not 100% sure that the issue is even with my code, unless I have misunderstood something.

I have distilled the issue into the simplest form I can, available at https://github.com/sparkeh9/XamarinFormsListViewIssue.

So, I have a HorizontalListView control utilising a very simple data template selector (no logic, returns a single data template)

[See XAML screenshot](https://github.com/sparkeh9/XamarinFormsListViewIssue/blob/master/simple_xaml.JPG)

[See Template Selector screenshot](https://github.com/sparkeh9/XamarinFormsListViewIssue/blob/master/template_selector.JPG)

My issue is, when I use a template selector, when calling `ItemTemplateSelector.CreateContent()` in order to start generating UI controls based on the template, it throws an exception [See exception screenshot](https://github.com/sparkeh9/XamarinFormsListViewIssue/blob/master/exception.jpg) which claims that the LoadTemplate property should not be null.  I have looked at the base classes and found that this property is a `Func<object>` which is private, and can only be set from outside by calling a specific constructor.

If I specify a literal item template in the XAML, everything works as expected, such as:

```
<controls:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Text="test"></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>
```

EDIT: Answered my own question

Comment: It might be nonsense, but if you specify both an `ItemTemplateSelector` and an `ItemTemplate`, wouldn't one override the other? Maybe it's what causing the issue? Nevertheless, please post the entire `HorizontalListView.Style`

Comment: I added ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector after experiencing the issue, it was just to prove that it was the selector causing the issue :)

Comment: Also, there is no style defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what I had done wrong - if the type is DataTemplateSelector, then you must first generate a template by calling `ItemTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate( item, null )`, after which point you can call `CreateContent()`

[diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKakn.jpg)

I've committed this to demonstrate what I mean:
https://github.com/sparkeh9/XamarinFormsListViewIssue/commit/f2f0d807d2d463d1fe9e6a89f0d3c0c7676a0761